# Inserting data from CSV to DB, Double Quotes Issue using Spring Batch

Tags: java, csv, spring-batch, double-quotes

While inserting data from csv to db using Spring Batch, some of rows are not inserting due two double quotes( one quote default, second quote along with data). 
Sample csv data:

```
"1","abc","xyz",""Hyderabad""
```

or

```
 "1","abc","xyz","\"Hyderabad\""
```

expected DB row:

```
1  abc  xyz  "Hyderabad"
```

Here City value must with double quotes.

Can anybody help on this.

Comment: You need to give some more details. What the issue you are facing now? What happens when you currently run the process. What does your current configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `""` when you import data from csv and change this using `replaceAll` method to format whatever you like before you will send it to DB.

Just remember:

1) Strings are immutable in Java, so you need to reassign value, like here:

```
sampleString = sampleString.replaceAll("from", "to").
```

2) also -> you can escape quote `"` using `\"`

Next time, please remember that it would be easier to answer if you will provide more code to see what you have done or at least exception you receive.

Comment: FYI - csv contains more than 1lac records with 500 columns, here I am not using POJOs, Straight away inserting data into db with out manipulation. Any suggestion DB side...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using a `FlatFileItemReader` to read your CSV. In that case, as you may know, you can change the quote character via the `DelimitedLineTokenizer` quoteCharacter property :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">  
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">  
                    <property name="quoteCharacter" value='"' /> 
                </bean>  
             </property>  
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can also extend the class `DelimitedLineTokenizer` to override the method `isQuoteCharacter`, but it can only take a single character at a time.

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;

public class CustomDelimitedLineTokenizer extends DelimitedLineTokenizer {

    @Override
    protected boolean isQuoteCharacter(char c) {
        // Your logic here
        return true/false;
    }

}
```

So I'm not sure what you're asking is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 quotes like this:

```
"1","abc","xyz","""Hyderabad"""
```

The outer quotes are needed to indicate there are quotes inside (which should stay there), and the inside quote needs to be 'escaped' with an extra quote.